# React - Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am using the devicon-react-svg module to render Devicons in my portfolio. However when I use

```
{icons.map((icon, i) => (
    <DevIcon
      key={i}
      icon={icon}
      className={styles.devIcon}
    />
))}
```

the Icons ARE rendered properly. However when I switch components through routing (go to another page in my portfolio) I get the error in the title and the component that I routed to is not rendered (i.e. page is blank). I have no clue why this is happening since I don't understand the error. Anyone knows why this might be happening? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The issue seems to be with routing and switching. Consider including them in a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Were you able to solve it?